# TSQL to return NO or YES instead TRUE or FALSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I show a different value if some columns return FALSE,

for example,

COLUMN "BASIC" returns FALSE, but I need show for the user YES or NO. Case FALSE, return NO.

Comment: There are no Boolean true/false columns in SQL Server. Tell us what is the data type of column BASIC.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If varchar or bit, handling NULLs

```
case
    when BASIC = 'FALSE' then 'NO'
    when BASIC <> 'FALSE' then 'YES'
    else 'UNDEFINED'
end
```

or if just bit

```
case
    when BASIC = 1 then 'YES'
    when BASIC = 0 then 'NO'
    else 'UNDEFINED'
end
```

Edit:

```
SELECT 
    TipoImovel_Id AS TII_SEQ,
    Descricao AS TII_DSC, 
    Sigla AS TII_DSC_SIGLA,
    -- choose which one you want from the answers here
    case
        when BASIC = 1 then 'YES'
        when BASIC = 0 then 'NO'
        else 'UNDEFINED'
    end AS SomeColumnName
FROM San_TipoImovel";
```

Comment: but how can I put this in my query ? "SELECT TipoImovel_Id AS TII_SEQ, Descricao AS TII_DSC, Sigla AS TII_DSC_SIGLA, basic FROM San_TipoImovel"; The basic I need return YES or NO case TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 8):

since SQL 2012 you can use IIF function

```
IIF(BASIC = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
case when column = 'FALSE' then 'NO' else 'YES' end
```

Comment: but how can I put this in my query ? "SELECT TipoImovel_Id AS TII_SEQ, Descricao AS TII_DSC, Sigla AS TII_DSC_SIGLA, basic FROM San_TipoImovel";    The basic I need return YES or NO case TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement:

```
case BASIC when 'True' then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' end
```

Comment: You need to wrap your literals in single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT TipoImovel_Id AS TII_SEQ, Descricao AS TII_DSC, Sigla AS TII_DSC_SIGLA, case when basic = 'FALSE' then 'NO' else 'YES' end 
FROM San_TipoImovel
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user defined function so in the future you can just say something like:

```
select dbo.YesNo(Active) from APAccount
```

here is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].YesNo(@Value Bit)
    RETURNS varchar(3)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @R as varchar(3)

      SET @R =
        (
        Select 
            case 
                when @Value = 1 then 'Yes'
                else 'No'
            end
        )
       RETURN @R
    END
```