# Return Bit Value as 1/0 and NOT True/False in SQL Server

Tags: sql, select, bit

I have a Table in SQL Server 2000 with BitValue Column. But, it is being displayed as True/False in SQL Server Management Studio. When I do a `Select * from Tablename` it returns the BitValue Column values as True/False.
How do I force it to return the value as bits (1/0) instead of True/False?
Any Help will be really appreciated?

Comment: Why are you concerned about the display format of a boolean value in SSMS?

Comment: I'm using those values, doing some work and inserting the values again to that table. But I cannot insert the values as True/False because it throws an error saying something like bit value only accepts 1 or 0.

Comment: `True` is just how SSMS displays a column of type `bit` with value `1`.  A C# client would receive a value `SqlBoolean.True`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [TSQL to return NO or YES instead TRUE or FALSE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8051839/1563878). I think that Sql Server not returns TRUE or FALSE, please see this [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx).

Comment: This Fails: Update Table Set BitField=True Where ID=1
But this works: Update Table Set BitField=1 Where ID=1

Answer (score 42):

Try with this script, maybe will be useful:

```
SELECT CAST('TRUE' as bit) -- RETURN 1
SELECT CAST('FALSE' as bit) --RETURN 0
```

Anyway I always would use a value of 1 or 0 (not TRUE or FALSE). Following your example, the update script would be:

```
Update Table Set BitField=CAST('TRUE' as bit) Where ID=1
```

Answer (score 25):

Modify your query to generate the output that you want.

Try casting them to int:

```
select cast(bitFlag as int)
```

Or, if you like, use `case`:

```
select (case when bitFlag = 0 then 0 else 1 end)
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be changed to 0/1 through using `CASE WHEN` like this example:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN SchemaName.TableName.BitFieldName = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'bit Value' 
 FROM SchemaName.TableName
```

Answer (score -1):

just you pass this things in your select query. using CASE

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN gender=0 THEN 'Female' 
        WHEN gender=1 THEN 'Male'
    END 
as Gendership from Tablename;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Try this:- SELECT Case WHEN COLUMNNAME=0 THEN 'sex'
              ELSE WHEN COLUMNNAME=1 THEN 'Female' END AS YOURGRIDCOLUMNNAME FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

in your query for only true or false column