# data too long for this column mysql error

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
update slcm.m_user_master set Is_Active = '1' where M_USER_ID = '1'
```

while updating table it showing message data too long for this column .
I have taken database IsActive database as bit.

```
this is table description
e Table

CREATE TABLE `m_user_master` (
  `M_USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_Type_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `M_User_Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `M_User_Name_Hindi` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Login_ID` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Password` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Mobile_No` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Email_ID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Updated_By` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Updated_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Active` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Active_From` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Active_To` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_By` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`M_USER_ID`),
  KEY `FK_M_User_Master_M_User_Type_Master` (`User_Type_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_M_User_Master_M_User_Type_Master` FOREIGN KEY (`User_Type_ID`) REFERENCES `m_user_type_master` (`User_Type_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show the table description

Comment: M_USER_IDint(11) NOT NULL
User_Type_IDint(11) NULL
M_User_Namevarchar(50) NULL
M_User_Name_Hindivarchar(50) NULL
User_Login_IDvarchar(30) NULL
User_Passwordvarchar(30) NULL
User_Mobile_Noint(12) NULL
User_Email_IDvarchar(50) NULL
Created_Datedatetime NULL
Updated_Byvarchar(50) NULL
Updated_Datedatetime NULL
Is_Activebit(1) NULL
Active_Fromdatetime NULL
Active_Todatetime NULL
Created_Byvarchar(50) NULL

Comment: Please add it to your question using the edit function. Not as comment

Comment: for `bit` data-type the approach for adding a value is to prepend with `b` so in your case its `b'1'` check the doc here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html

Comment: Why do you need any more of the table description then what's been provided?

Answer (score 3):

Try the value for `Is_Active` without quotes like so:

```
update slcm.m_user_master set Is_Active = 1 where M_USER_ID = '1'
```

It's expecting a true/false (1/0) value which takes a single bit to store for `Is_Active` and it's getting a string instead which takes a byte or 8 bits to store. Hence the "too long" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
update slcm.m_user_master set Is_Active = 1 where M_USER_ID = 1
```

and you can see this :

> [Return Bit Value as 1/0 and NOT True/False in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451413/return-bit-value-as-1-0-and-not-true-false-in-sql-server)