# Get Invoke-Sqlcmd to show '0' and '1' for BIT columns

Tags: sql-server, powershell

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` displays 'True' or 'False' for BIT columns.

`SSMS` displays '1' or '0' for BIT columns.

Yes, you and I know that 0=false and 1=true. Some more "business-oriented" users want to see it just like SSMS does it.

I can think of code to do it, but it is not brief. How can I get `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to display '0' and '1' for BIT column values?

```
SELECT TOP 1 value FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options;
```

Output in SSMS:

[image: Output is SSMS]

Output in PowerShell console:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ADB -TrustServerCertificate -Query 'SELECT TOP 1 value FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options;'

value
-----
 True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update it sounds like you have the *same* problem as the one in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17451413/447901), so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17451546/45375) there offers a solution, based on *modifying your queries*:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cast(value as int) FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options;
```

*If you don't want to modify your queries*, you'll need to resort to *post-processing*, which, however, is (a) more cumbersome and (b) performs worse:

```bash
$query = 'SELECT TOP 1 value FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options;'

# An ordered helper hashtable (dictionary) for storing
# copies of each input object's properties, from which
# a [pscustomobject] can be constructed.
$helperDict = [ordered] @{}

Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $query <# ... #> |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Fill the helper dictionary with the current row's
    # properties, translating [bool] into [int] values.
    foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {
      $name, $value = $prop.Name, $prop.Value
      # Exclude standard properties of DataRow instances.
      if ($name -in 'RowError', 'RowState', 'Table', 'ItemArray', 'HasErrors') { continue }
      $helperDict[$name] = if ($value -is [bool]) { [int] $value } else { $value }
    }
    # Construct and output a custom object from the helper dictionary.
    [pscustomobject] $helperDict    
  }
```

Note:

- Since the data types of the properties of [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataRow) instances are immutable, updating them *directly* is not an option, so the above creates `[pscustomobject]` *copies* of them, including only those properties that represent actual column values (by explicitly including standard properties).
- You could optimize the above by caching the names of the properties as well as the names of those that have `[bool]` values after having analyzed the first row, which saves you from having to use reflection in each iteration.

---

*If you additionally want (modified) `DataRow` instances as output*, a different approach is required; here it is wrapped in a custom function, `Convert-BitColumsToInt`:

```bash
# Accepts a stream of DataRow objects, assumed to be from the same
# table, such as output by Invoke-SqlCmd,
# and creates modified copies with [bool] column values replaced
# by [int] ones.
function Convert-BitColumsToInt {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [System.Data.DataRow] $InputObject
  )
  begin {
    $dateTableClone = $null
  }
  process {
    if ($null -eq $dateTableClone) { # First row received.
      # Create an empty clone of the input objects' data table.
      $dataTableClone = $InputObject.Table.Clone()
      # Change the data type of [bool] columns to [int]
      foreach ($col in $dataTableClone.Columns.Where({ $_.DataType -eq [bool] })) {
        $col.DataType = [int]
      }
    }
    # Copy the row's values to a new row in the clone, which implicitly
    # converts the [bool] values to [int], and pass the new row through
    # (thanks to enclosure in (...))
    ($dataTableClone.Rows.Add($InputObject.ItemArray))
    $dataTableClone.Clear()
  }
}

# Sample call
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $query <# ... #> | 
  Convert-BitColumsToInt
```

Comment: I will see what can be done with that. I was hoping not to change the SQL.

Comment: Most current SQL Server instances will likely have this table.  The `value` column is a 'BIT' datatype. `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ADB -TrustServerCertificate -Query 'SELECT value FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options;'` The output it produces is `value : True`.

Comment: It appears that all of those tables (and 2016, 2017, 2019, and 2022)  show `bit` mapping to CLR data type `Boolean`. This one is 2016. PowerShell 7.3.8.

Comment: Yes, using SqlServer module. `(Get-Command -Name Invoke-Sqlcmd).Module.Version.ToString()` reports 22.2.0.

Comment: @lit: I see. I missed that your `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command targeting `master.dbo.MSreplication_options` seemingly _does_ return `[bool]` instances. So under what conditions does it not and returns `0` and `1` instead?

Comment: My sincerest apologies. The goal is to get the PowerShell console to display what SSMS displays. The question is updated. I beg your forgiveness.

Comment: After setting `$prop.Value = [int]$prop.Value`, using `$prop.Value.GetType()` still reports `Boolean`. I see `Add-Member` and `Get-Member`, but is there anything like `Remove-Member`?

Comment: @lit - good point; I should have tested with real `DataRow` instances. Please see my update, which constructs _copies_ of the input rows, as `[psustomobject]` instances.

Comment: This is looking pretty good. I think I could make a filter function to do it.  Can you suggest any way to convert the `OrderedDictionary` into a `DataRow` for output?

Comment: @lit: Please see my update. A filter function wouldn't work, but an advanced one does, as shown.

Comment: Many thanks, @mklement. I think this will work. I believe I have a filter function to which `Invoke-Sqlcmd` can pipe DataRows and it will change the Booleans into Ints. Please suggest a better name than `Convert-DataRowBoolToInt`.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @lit. Coming up with a name that is not too verbose is tough; yours sounds OK; perhaps _column_ should also be in the name?

Comment: Now, I am sure to be asked to change $null values into 'NULL'. "Just like SSMS!"

Comment: @lit:  It shouldn't be too hard to extend the existing function if that happens. Btw, can I suggest removing the original, obsolete part of your question?